# What timezone(zone, timestamp) of Postgresql does?

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I am trying to add timezone to date and it is resulting a strange result.
Here is my query

```
SELECT  timezone('GMT+5:30','2014-03-15'::date);
```

And resulting value is

```
"2014-03-14 13:00:00" (timestamp without timezone)
```

Can anyone explains why it is returning "2014-03-14 13:00:00" for '2014-03-15'

And my timezone is `Asia/Calcutta(GMT+5:30)`

Comment: What is your sessions time zone? `SHOW timezone;`

Comment: Sessions timezone is this `"Asia/Calcutta"` @vyegorov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you might know, PostgreSQL allows function overloading.
To check all possible functions named `timezone`, run this query:

```sql
SELECT proname,pg_get_function_result(oid),pg_get_function_arguments(oid)
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc
 WHERE proname ~ '^timezone$';
```

As you see, none of them accepts `date` type as argument. It is quite valid in fact, as time zones have no meaning without time component.
Therefore, your input it converted to `timestamp with time zone` (based on the resulting datatype you've mentioned), which is `2014-03-15 00:00:00+XX`, where `XX` depend on your location.

And, if you're located well ahead of `GMT`, this results in time substraction to return you timestamp at the desired zone.

What is reported by this query:

```sql
SELECT current_timestamp, setting
  FROM pg_settings
 WHERE name = 'TimeZone';
```

---

**UPDATE**

Yes, this *is* tricky stuff. I highly recommend to read through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170) a couple of times.

Please, do the following:

```
SET TimeZone TO 'Asia/Calcutta'; -- you don't have to do this
SELECT ts AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', ts AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
       row_number() OVER () rn
  FROM (VALUES (now()),
/* 2 */ ('2014-03-15'::date),
/* 3 */ ('2014-03-15'::date::timestamptz),
/* 4 */ ('2014-03-15'::date::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'),
/* 5 */ ('2014-03-15'::date::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'),
/* 6 */ ('2014-03-15'::timestamp),
/* 7 */ (timezone('GMT+5:30','2014-03-15')),
/* 8 */ (timezone('GMT+5:30','2014-03-15'::date)),
/* 9 */ (timezone('GMT+5:30','2014-03-15'::timestamp)),
/*10 */ (timezone('GMT+5:30','2014-03-15'::timestamp)  AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'),
/*11 */ (timezone('GMT+5:30','2014-03-15'::timestamptz)),
/*12 */ (timezone('GMT+5:30','2014-03-15'::timestamptz)  AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')) t(ts);
```

and check the output.

Your case corresponds to row `#4` here. You do have `2014-03-14 18:30:00` here,
but as you're in time zone `+05:30` and function should return `timestamp without time zone`, you're getting `2014-03-14 13:00:00` as a result.

Please, find more bout [these types in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) and also [check `AT TIME ZONE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) construct.

Comment: As my time zone is `"Asia/Calcutta"` that is `GMT+5:30`, I should get `"2014-10-14 18:30:00" ((2014-03-15 00:00:00) - 5:30)`. Instead I am getting `"2014-10-14 13:00:00"`